# Excel 2010 - date format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Hi I want to look up a date and return financial year week but when I use `vlookup` the date is in `dd/mm/yy hh:mm` format. This means the number value is `42461.33` so wont change to `dd/mm/yy 42461` format. Is there anyway of removing the `hh mm` from a date and time to show the number format as `42461` so that it looks up the `dd/mm/yy` on the v look up list.

for example the cell I am copying the date from is - `01/04/2016  08:00:00` I want to change that to `01/04/16` so that it looks up a list of dates finds `01/04/16` and tells me that is financial week 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not with the format, is with the actual value.  Dates are stored as floating point numbers, in units of days.  Changing the format won't change how the date is stored, or how vlookup matches it. In this image, the third column shows the value that excel has in mind when it shows you the value in the second column.

[image]

You need to retrieve only the day portion, so use `rounddown(YourDate,0)`  This can happen inside your vlookup formula, of course.  For instance, if your lookup table is in c2:d367, and the date you are looking up is in A1:

`vlookup(rounddown(A1,0), $c$2:$d$367,2)`

Comment: I disagree; why destroy the part of the data you don't want to see? It is better to adjust the format to not show it.

Comment: @Aganju Because adjusting the format  won't change how it matches in vlookup - only how it display on the screen.

Comment: excellent thank you so much Adam that worked perfectly :-) No it does change it Aganju it then looks up the date in the v look up correctly if you dont do it this way it wont find it in the vlook up because the number value is different

Comment: All that said, have you looked at the `weeknum()` function to see if it does what you want?  `weeknum(42373.33,21)` returns `1`.

Comment: @marieGreig, just so you don't overlook a key point in this answer:  using VLOOKUP for this kind of purpose typically entails an exact match.  You can sometimes do a match on the "raw" value as stored if you structure the formula right.  However, odds are that a stored date/time value will be an inexact floating point number; there will be insignificant decimal value errors that will prevent an exact match.  As a general practice, do VLOOKUP against values that have been stored as exact numbers, like a rounded date or an extracted date function value.

Comment: @marieGreig, BTW, if this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  It indicates that the problem has been solved, and helps to identify proven solutions for other users with a similar issue.  It also awards a little rep to both of you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The date format you'd need is "dd/mm/yy", simply enter it under Format/Custom (if it is not already in the list to pick from).